# SharedPreferences - Preferences Connection possible?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

Assume I have one Preference XML file and another SharedPreference (public scope)

Is there a way to link the preference XML file to my shared prefrence object ??

like giving my prefrence xml file a refrence to shared prefrence object

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally used a alternative instead 
made loads of class variables and used preference on change listeners